# Workflow for compiling and installing software with Puppet

Tags: puppet

I need to manually compile and install FFMPEG as one of my dependencies using Puppet manifests. I want to do this myself to customize the configuration of FFMPEG to the needs of my project.

I'm not sure as to how to structure the entire process with classes. The logic should go something like this:

1. If `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` doesn't exist, compile:

   1. Install build dependencies from apt-get.
   2. Create a directory for the library sources `/tmp/ffmpeg`
   3. Download and compile the Yasm assembler

      1. Download.
      2. Extract.
      3. Configure
      4. Make
      5. Make Install
   4. Download and compile x264

      1. Clone the source.
      2. Configure.
      3. Make
      4. Make Install
   5. Download and compile fdk-aac:

      1. ...
   6. ....

I can easily branch all of these out into their own modules and declare them as dependencies of FFMPEG, that's not the problem.

My main problem is understanding how to do the whole download/extract/compile process for each module *only if it's not already present on the system.*

How do I structure my classes to only act if the software is not already installed?

Comment: You're using a package manager for ffmpeg; the package manager will handle required dependencies.

Comment: I'm not using a package manager for FFMPEG. I need to compile it myself for the codecs I need, otherwise `package { "ffmpeg": ensure => present }` would do everything I need. No, that would be too easy.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how you go about it, you need a way to check whether your custom installation has been installed.

Common methods include

- checking a file and running a command only if it is not present: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-creates
- running a command only if another command returns 0: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec-attribute-onlyif (alternatively, the `unless` attribute)